# Nested object using square bracket notation in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use square bracket notation instead of literal in order use PHP with my name pairs.

Here as literal notation:

```
$selector.plugin({
  item: 'something',
  item2: true,
  item3: {
    option1: 60,
    option2: 10
  }
});
```

Here is what I have for square bracket notation:

```
var items = {};
var options = {};

items['item'] = '.item';
items['item2'] = true;
items['item3'] = options;
options['option1'] = 60;
options['option2'] = 10;

$selector.plugin(items);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Again how do you nest objects in another using square bracket notation?

Comment: You can't have multiple properties with the same name in an object. How would you be able to differentiate between them.

Comment: thats just an example used for syntax

Comment: I modified the question for better understanding.

Comment: What doesn't work about the given example?

Comment: I am trying to be efficient also allowing php to be the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be invalid.

If you define something like this:

```
var test = {
  option:1,
  option:2,
  option:3
};
```

How would you select each different option?  You couldn't.

An alternative would be:

```
var example = {
  items:[
    {selector:".item", option:[10, 60]},
    {selector:".otheritem", option:[20, 40]}
  ]
}
```

(Just to give you an idea.)